# How can I export a custom markup back into AutoCAD

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-designautomation, objectarx

I have implemented a custom markup option like described in [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/implementing-custom-markups) and I'm looking for a way to place the custom markup on the original AutoCAD DWG file using the DesignAutomation v3 API and a custom ObjectArx C# AutoCAD plugin.

I've looked around in the ObjectArx documentation, and it doesn't look like it's possible to directly place an SVG in a DWG file, so I think my best option would be to convert the SVG commands into AutoCAD shapes and group them. Does anyone have a script to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some ideas, after the markup data of SVG (from the context of Forge Viewer )is ready, you could try to organize the data:

- For standard shape such as line, circle, polyline, text etc, build the corresponding types of entities in AutoCAD : circle, line, polyline. Of course, apply color/line weight with AutoCAD entities. Both ObjectARX or .NET API of AutoCAD can easily create such entities.
- For non-standard shape such as irregular cloud markup, get discrete points, and build Solid entity in AutoCAD. A few years ago when it was AutoCAD Design Automation v2, I made a sample that adds signature in AutoCAD, after getting data from Forge Viewer app.
  https://github.com/xiaodongliang/ViewData-DWG-TitleBlock-Signature

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to convert my SVG to a PNG and then create a solid object just like you did in your example. I'm having a little trouble scaling it correctly, but I'll let you know if I can't figure that out after looking into it more